# What is the error in this OLEDB insert Command?

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

```
  public void log(int materialId,string materialName, string action, string description, string datetime, double amount,string unit)
        {
            OleDbCommand insertIntoLog = new OleDbCommand();
            insertIntoLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO NCCI_eventslog (materialId,materialName,action,description,date_time,amount,unit) Values (@materialId,@materialName,@action,@description,@date_time,@amount,@unit)";
            insertIntoLog.Connection = database;
            insertIntoLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@materialId", materialId);
            insertIntoLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@materialName", materialName);
            insertIntoLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@action", action);
            insertIntoLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", description);
            insertIntoLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_time", datetime);
            insertIntoLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", amount);
            insertIntoLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit", unit);

            if (database.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                database.Close();
            }
            database.Open();
            insertIntoLog.ExecuteScalar();
        }
```

The error is : Syntax error in the Insert Statement, I copied the insert statement in Access Query SQL and no errors 
What is the problem ?

Comment: What is the actual provider? OLEDB is just the transport - the SQL needs to work for the target database/etc. So: what is that here?

Comment: Try the ninja option, add an `;` at the end and see what happens :) (I've gotten issues with this when using the Oracle provider.)

Comment: Parameters are not "@" named with OLEDB. You have to replace them by question marks "?".

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
insertIntoLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

instead of

```
insertIntoLog.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: meh; usually that would still work - it'll just return `null` if there are no rows; I certainly wouldn't expect it to show as a **syntax** error (because: it isn't one)

Comment: I agree usually it should still work, I think maybe its only the SqlClient one where it works

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik it should work generally; to quote from `DbCommand` : "If the first column of the first row in the result set is not found, a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) is returned."

Answer (score 1):

The OLEDB provider doesn't support named parameters for text commands - use `?` for each parameter and then add them to the command ***in order***:

```
insertIntoLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO NCCI_eventslog " + 
    "(materialId,materialName,action,description,date_time,amount,unit) " + 
    "Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: No the way he's doing it with the @ will definitely work

Answer (score 0):

Check your Datetime Field may be that is your problem I feel 
first manually pass datetime value '01/jan/2013' and check

Comment: datetimes passed *as `DateTime`s* usually won't cause any issue (it is, however, not good practice to pass them around as strings)

Comment: as your db what datatype you set

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, so feel free to downvote me I suppose, but because I don't think any of the "answers" given so far are correct, I thought I might as well throw this out there, even though this question is like a year old now.

"Unit" might be a reserved keyword, or one of the other ones could be keywords. So I would suggest putting it in square brackets. So your INSERT statement would look like this:

```
insertIntoLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO NCCI_eventslog (materialId,materialName,action,description,date_time,amount,[unit]) Values (@materialId,@materialName,@action,@description,@date_time,@amount,@unit)";
```

If that doesn't work try putting other ones in brackets, or even all of them, I don't think putting all of them would hurt it in anyway.

I guess you could also try changing your formatting to the way D Stanley suggested, but I know from experience that you do not have to do it that way.